# Retrofitting Windows Event Log to a Delphi 5 app

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, event-log

I'm looking for a (fairly pain-free) means of adding some Windows Application Event-Log support to a small legacy Delphi 5 application. We just want it to log when it starts-up, shuts-down, fails to connect to a database etc.

Several of the solutions/components I've seen seem to suggest that we'll need to make a resource DLL which the Windows Event Log Viewer will link to when trying to read our 'entries'. While this doesn't seem too onerous, I guess it's something else to keep in mind if/when we further develop the application in future - we'll need to keep this DLL up to date.

At some point in the future we will want to turn the application into a service, probably written in D2007.

So can anyone recommend a suitable route for adding events to the event log in D5? I'm looking for specific '*we used this and it was okay*' comments rather than a Google trawl (which I can do myself!) Free or paid-for, really don't mind - but something that I could migrate to D2007 in the future is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *J* and Peter's responses, I got my code writing into the event log straight away. There is a little bit more to do, particularly if you want your events to appear 'nicely' in the event log without a standard windows message about not being able to find the description (as per the bottom of *J*'s post).

I followed the tips [here](http://texhex.blogspot.com/2004/09/creating-event-message-file-for-event.html) to making a suitable DLL and entering it into the registry, and very quickly had it all sorted out.

This was all in Delphi5, as per the question, but I've seen nothing that makes me think it wouldn't also work in D2007.

Comment: I accepted this as my answer simply because it wraps-up J and Peter's response and links to the other bits and pieces you have to do. I'm not going to gain any rep from it :-)

Answer (score 6):

*Summary: Writing to the Windows Event Log using Delphi*

---

If you are writing a Windows Service and need to write to the local machine's Windows Event Log then you can call 
[TService.**LogMessage**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.SvcMgr.TService.LogMessage) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303253/any-light-for-teventlogger/1303290#1303290).

```
//TMyTestService = class(TService)

procedure TMyTestService.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  LogMessage('This is an error.');
  LogMessage('This is another error.', EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE);
  LogMessage('This is information.', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
  LogMessage('This is a warning.', EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE);
end;
```

---

For any other type of applications you can use the SvcMgr.**TEventLogger** [undocumented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.SvcMgr.TEventLogger) helper class for TService to write the the local machine's Windows Event Log as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303253/any-light-for-teventlogger/1303290#1303290), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684919/retrofitting-windows-event-log-to-a-delphi-5-app/685235#685235) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/685342/119789).

```
uses
  SvcMgr;

procedure TForm1.EventLoggerExampleButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TEventLogger.Create('My Test App Name') do
  begin
    try
      LogMessage('This is an error.');
      LogMessage('This is another error.', EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE);
      LogMessage('This is information.', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
      LogMessage('This is a warning.', EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

You can also use the Windows API [**ReportEvent**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397934/writing-to-the-event-log-in-delphi/400104#400104) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303253/any-light-for-teventlogger/1303409#1303409).

I've created a simple class to make it easier, it is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/Kobus-Smit/EventLogHelper).

```
//----------------- EXAMPLE USAGE: ---------------------------------

uses
  EventLog;

procedure TForm1.EventLogExampleButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TEventLog.Source := 'My Test App Name';

  TEventLog.WriteError('This is an error.');
  TEventLog.WriteInfo('This is information.');
  TEventLog.WriteWarning('This is a warning.');
end;

//------------------------------------------------------------------


unit EventLog;

interface

type
  TEventLog = class
  private
    class procedure CheckEventLogHandle;
    class procedure Write(AEntryType: Word; AEventId: Cardinal; AMessage: string); static;
  public
    class var Source: string;
    class destructor Destroy;

    class procedure WriteInfo(AMessage: string); static;
    class procedure WriteWarning(AMessage: string); static;
    class procedure WriteError(AMessage: string); static;

    class procedure AddEventSourceToRegistry; static;
  end;

threadvar EventLogHandle: THandle;

implementation

uses Windows, Registry, SysUtils;

class destructor TEventLog.Destroy;
begin
  if EventLogHandle > 0 then
  begin
    DeregisterEventSource(EventLogHandle);
  end;
end;

class procedure TEventLog.WriteInfo(AMessage: string);
begin
  Write(EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 2, AMessage);
end;

class procedure TEventLog.WriteWarning(AMessage: string);
begin
  Write(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, 3, AMessage);
end;

class procedure TEventLog.WriteError(AMessage: string);
begin
  Write(EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 4, AMessage);
end;

class procedure TEventLog.CheckEventLogHandle;
begin
  if EventLogHandle = 0 then
  begin
   EventLogHandle := RegisterEventSource(nil, PChar(Source));
  end;
  if EventLogHandle <= 0 then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Could not obtain Event Log handle.');
  end;
end;

class procedure TEventLog.Write(AEntryType: Word; AEventId: Cardinal; AMessage: string);
begin
  CheckEventLogHandle;
  ReportEvent(EventLogHandle, AEntryType, 0, AEventId, nil, 1, 0, @AMessage, nil);
end;

// This requires admin rights. Typically called once-off during the application's installation
class procedure TEventLog.AddEventSourceToRegistry;
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if reg.OpenKey('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\' + Source, True) then
    begin
      reg.WriteString('EventMessageFile', ParamStr(0)); // The application exe's path
      reg.WriteInteger('TypesSupported', 7);
      reg.CloseKey;
    end
    else
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('Error updating the registry. This action requires administrative rights.');
    end;
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization

TEventLog.Source := 'My Application Name';

end.
```

---

[**ReportEvent**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) supports writing a log entry to either a local or remote machine's Event Log.  For a remote example see [John Kaster's EDN article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40404).

---

**Note that you would also have to [create a message file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363669(v=vs.85).aspx) and [register your event source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363634(VS.85).aspx)** otherwise all your log messages will be starting with something like this:

> The description for Event ID xxx from source xxxx cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:

1, For more information on how to create a message file see [Finn Tolderlund's tutorial](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/service/service.htm#Using%20LogMessage) or [Michael Hex's article](http://texhex.blogspot.com.au/2004/09/creating-event-message-file-for-event.html) 
or you can use an existing MC and [RES file included in the GitHub project](https://github.com/Kobus-Smit/EventLogHelper/tree/master/Test%20app/Source/MessageFile).

2, Embed the RES file into your application by including the MessageFile.res in your DPR file. Alternatively you can create a dll for the messages.

```
program MyTestApp;

uses
  Forms,
  FormMain in 'FormMain.pas' {MainForm},
  EventLog in 'EventLog.pas';

{$R *.res}
{$R MessageFile\MessageFile.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
```

3, The once-off registration requires admin rights writing to the registry so it us usually done as part of your application's installation process.

```
//For example
AddEventSourceToRegistry('My Application Name', ParamStr(0));
//or
AddEventSourceToRegistry('My Application Name', 'C:\Program Files\MyApp\Messages.dll');

//--------------------------------------------------

procedure AddEventSourceToRegistry(ASource, AFilename: string);
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if reg.OpenKey('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\' + ASource, True) then
    begin
      reg.WriteString('EventMessageFile', AFilename);
      reg.WriteInteger('TypesSupported', 7);
      reg.CloseKey;
    end
    else
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('Error updating the registry. This action requires administrative rights.');
    end;
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

If you have need Windows event logging and other logging requirements you can also use logging frameworks such as [log4d](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4d/) and [TraceTool](http://tracetool.sourceforge.net/)

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397934/writing-to-the-event-log-in-delphi) if you want to write to the Event Log window in the Delphi IDE.

Answer (score 4):

For simple event logging in D5, I have used the following code to add messages to the Applications log.

- Add "SvcMgr" to the uses clause
- Use this code to add your text message and an ID number (last parameter on LogMessage lines)

  ```
  with TEventLogger.create('My Application Name') do
  begin
    try
      LogMessage('Information Message!', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 1);
      LogMessage('Error Message!', EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 0, 2);
      LogMessage('Warning Message!', EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, 0, 3);
      LogMessage('Audit Success Message!', EVENTLOG_AUDIT_SUCCESS, 0, 4);
      LogMessage('Audit Failure Message!', EVENTLOG_AUDIT_FAILURE, 0, 5);
    finally
      free;
    end;
  end;
  ```

Comment: Thanks Peter - worked a treat. I'm just getting my head around what I need to do with the registry and resource DLLs to make it all clean and tidy. Cheers, Rob

Comment: Could you please tell which Windows Lib contains these functions? I really doubt it is smart idea to add whole unit !!! to use only few !!! functions within it ... Is it advapi32.dll or winnt.dll ... or which? Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3):

I use standard VCL for this in Delphi 6, I can't tell you whether or not this is available in Delphi 5. Try it for yourself and let us know if this stuff is there in D5.

1. Declare a global/form variable of type TEventLogger. This is declared in the SvcMgr unit so this unit will need to be added to your uses list. If this is a normal application (i.e. not a Service) then make sure SvcMgr is added after the Forms unit.

   MyEventLog: TEventLogger;
2. Create an instance of the logger.

   MyEventLog := TEventLogger.Create('MyApplication');
3. To write to the event log:

   MyEventLog.LogMessage('MyApplication started.'), EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
4. Don't forget to release it at the end:

   MyEventLog.Free;

There is other stuff you need to do to register the application with the Windows Event Log so that the message appears without this in front of it:

*The description for Event ID ( 1000 ) in Source ( Microsoft Internet Explorer ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. The following information is part of the event:*

Comment: Thanks - between this and Peter McMinn's answer I've got going. I'll come back and post an update with some info about setting up the registry/resource DLL once I've got it all working. Thanks again!