# Any light for TEventLogger?

Tags: delphi, event-log, helpfile

I want to see about logging events from a Delphi 5 application to the Windows log, and from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684919/retrofitting-windows-event-log-to-a-delphi-5-app) I see that I can use the `TEventLogger` class to do this.

However, I can't find any documentation on the syntax of the `TEventLogger.LogMessage` procedure, so I don't know what all the parameters mean, how to use them, or even what possible values are available.

I've tried looking around, and all I find is a page from Embarcadero stating that the function exists, but nothing on its syntax, and MSDN is no help as I can only find the BizTalk version which does me no good.

Does anyone have a help page or information on this that might shed some light on what I can do with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TEventLogger` is an internal helper class for `TService`.

You log message using the `TService.LogMessage()` function, not by calling into `TEventLogger` directly.  The parameters of `LogMessage()` directly match with the parameters of the Win32 API [`ReportEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Look in the Win32 API documentation for details.

If you are not writing a service application, then you need to call the Win32 API [`RegisterEventSource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363678(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ReportEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679(v=vs.85).aspx) functions directly instead.

Comment: This one'll be fun.  I'm eventually going to need both methods as the application can run as a service (which we want to make it into) or a standalone executable (which it currently is).  At least I know how to detect which mode it's running in and can switch appropriately.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 7):

A simple example of an application writing to the event log:

```
procedure WriteToLog(Msg:string; EventId: Word = 0);
var
  h: THandle;
begin
  h := RegisterEventSource(nil, PChar(Application.ExeName));
  if h > 0 then
  try
    ReportEvent(h, 0, 0, EventId, nil, 1, 0, @Msg, nil);
  finally
    DeregisterEventSource(h);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WriteToLog('* Blah Blah Blah *');
end;
```

But beware that not [registering the EventID with the system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363634(VS.85).aspx) will give this kind of confused Description:

> The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( C:\Documents and
>   Settings\fgaillard\My Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\Project1.exe )
>   cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary
>   registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a
>   remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to
>   retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The
>   following information is part of the event: * Blah Blah Blah *.